# Visual focus of Skip links

Tags: focus, accessibility, wai-aria, usability, skip

Is it important to place a focus indicator on a skip link destination even if the target is non interactive ? Do you believe that focus indicator should always be present in order to orient users to know where they are on a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, anything that isn't focusable should not have a focus indicator.

Just make sure that when you do skip to a section that the page scrolls to that page correctly so it is at the top (or near to the top) of the page (i.e. if you have a `position:fixed` header make sure that wherever you scroll to is not obscured by it).

For a "sighted" user the page change and location will be evident, for a "non-sighted" user on a screen reader their screen reader will guide them as long as you have managed focus correctly onto the non-focusable item (so make sure you use `tabindex="-1"` so you don't break this pattern if doing this programatically rather than with an anchor).

I use "sighted" and "non-sighted" here as obviously some people use a screen reader who do not have a sight impairment but it is easier to use this for illustration purposes.

What this boils down to is "expected behaviour", which is a key part of accessibility.

It is expected that anything with a focus indicator is interactive, adding focus indicators to non-interactive elements is a bad idea for this reason.

Secondly it is expected behaviour that a skip link will scroll the page to the relevant section, heading etc. As long as this happens your users will be fine.

The [only reference I can find on W3C on focus visible enhanced](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible-enhanced) says:

> Some elements can take focus (such as the target of a skip link), however, it is only when the element is operable by keyboard controls that this criterion applies.

Comment: _"For a "sighted" user the page change and location will be evident[...] it is expected behaviour that a skip link will scroll the page"_. There is an uncommon case here, which is that there won't be any scrolling on pages that are short enough to fit entirely in the viewport. I don't think it warrants any special handling though.